# How is it that powered speakers appear to deliver more power than they take?

Tags: power, speakers

As just one example, [this spec](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjIndXhk83SAhXLwrwKHYipBDQQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jblpro.com%2FProductAttachments%2Fspecs%5B1%5D.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGOf52yCPSv0YAK6LCEWCdRJZRxlw&sig2=6spPJxGnFzJFYV7v7sBEAQ) of a JBL 15 G2 says:

> 300 watts low-frequency and 100 watts high-frequency (bi-amplified) -
>   actual power delivered to the drivers.

and also says:

> 110 - 230 VAC, 50 - 60 Hz., 175 watts

I can only imagine that these ratings are being measured differently.  But I can't figure how.

(just to make sure it wasn't simply a typo, I found [another example](http://mackie.com/sites/default/files/PRODUCT%20RESOURCES/SPECS/Spec_Sheets/Thump12_Thump15_SS.pdf) : 500W RMS speaker power, 130W power supply)

Comment: Speakers have long been rated "optimistically".  Alternative facts....

Comment: Yeah - but this seems beyond optimistic.   The JBL one goes as far as saying "actual power delivered to the drivers".   Is there really no other explanation other than "absolute nonsense"?

Comment: Big output capacitor for one single 300W bounce.

Comment: Well, if you have some energy stored in capacitors you could deliver much more than the input power on a transient basis.  But you can't violate Pout = Pin*efficiency so absolute nonsense has a part to play.

Comment: Peak power - say from the moment the drumstick hits the snare drum - is much higher than average power (RMS measurement) allowing exaggerated peak power claims. The power supply rating is more honest, and an RMS power measurement would be at best 70% of that.

Comment: Also, the power consumption is often specced at something other than peak/max RMS amplifier power (i.e. 1/8th power). Well-specified speakers will make a note of this, others will not.

Comment: What's "1/8th power"?

Comment: It (should) mean that the parameter in question has been measured with an input signal of typical pink noise, which has a crest factor of 12 dB and is often used to represent "typical" audio content. That is, it is closer to typical audio content than white noise, or a pure sine wave (or at least that is the hope).

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!  A good concept to be aware of.  I guess you want to measure input power in a way that makes it as low as possible and output power in a way that makes it as high as possible :)

Comment: marketing prefer peak power

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's down to crest factor for real analogue signals like speech: -

[image]

The avaerage power is very much lower than the peak power. Compare music/speech with a sine wave: -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the old ridiculous "PMPO" rating which was about 20 times the RMS rating. So you had a 5W ghetto blaster being rated at 100W PMPO, and so on. Marketing and science exist in universes where truth has different meanings.

Answer (score 0):

> I can only imagine that these ratings are being measured differently.

yes, they are. one could be peak / instantaneous power and another is rms - there could be perfectly good rationale for that. one is honest and another is not as honest.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to speakers power is a different measure from electrical power.

It's literally about how much "BANG" you can get out of the speaker.

It kind of comes back the Watts vs kW.hr thing. Sure it can whack the woofer with a 300W pulses and make a really load noise.. which as a consumer, is what you care about. However, sound doesn't work that way and is never continuous.

The fact that it really only uses 0.175kw.hrs... nobody cares.